# Error al enviar la petición post con angularJS y C#

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

estoy tratando de enviar una petición post al api de c# desde angularjs.

En el servicio estoy enviando también un archivo adjunto, pero a la hora de validar que el api lleguen los datos, están llegado todos nulos.

Así estoy enviando la petición desde el angular.

Ya valide que la solicitud y el archivo lleguen llenos

```
        var response = $q.defer();
        var formData = new FormData();

        formData.append("data", solicitud);
        formData.append("files", archivo);


        $http.post("./api/AdministrarSolicitudes", {

              headers: {"Content-type": undefined}
            , transformRequest: formData
            , data: { data: solicitud , files: archivo }  

        }).then(successCallback, errorCallback);

        function successCallback(e) {

            var resultado = {
                error: false
                , mensaje: ""
                , data: e.data
            }

            response.resolve(resultado);
        };

        function errorCallback(e) {

            var resultado = {
                error: true
                , mensaje: ""
                , data: e.data
            }

            response.reject(resultado);
        };

        return response.promise;
```

Así tengo el api de c#

```
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post(DominioRMOSolicitud dominioSolicitudRMO)
    {
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
    }
```

Comment: pero "archivo", el que envias en el json, que es lo que contiene? estas enviando el file encodeado como base64? que tipo de datos defines en DominioRMOSolicitud  para files ?

Comment: @LeandroTuttini  Estoy intentando enviar los datos sin el archivo  y sigue llegando vació. Creo que el error esta acá ,                             
 data: { data: solicitud , files: archivo }    Pero no se como solucionarlo..., La petición si se envía así o tengo algún error?

Comment: como defines la clase DominioRMOSolicitud ? o sea el parametro dominioSolicitudRMO llega en null, o las propiedades son las que estan sin dato. Porque defines el Content-type como undefined en lugar de indicar que es json?

Comment: @LeandroTuttini  Buenas, si el dominio llega nullo, pero en el angular va lleno. yo me baso en este ejemplo para mi proyecto https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/post-json-data-and-files-in-same-request-with-angularjs-and/

Comment: ojo porque en el ejemplo veo un transformRequest que en tu ejemplo asignas formData, pero esto no tiene nada que ver. Revisa el ejemplo nuevamente porque no es lo mismo que estas realizando. El file que asigna es el $scope.files que seria un byte array, no veo que en tu caso sea lo mismo.

Answer (score 0):

Basado en el ejemplo del articulo

[Post JSON data And Files In Same Request With AngularJS And Web API](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/post-json-data-and-files-in-same-request-with-angularjs-and/)

que usas de guia, veo algunos puntos que no los aplicas de la misma forma

- En el ejemplo veo un `transformRequest` que en tu ejemplo asignas formData, pero esto no tiene nada que ver con la function que define para convertir el file antes de enviarlo en el post
- El file que asigna es el `$scope.files`, el cual se bindea por medio del `seletedFile`, ya que el ejemplo permite subir multiples archivos. En tu implementacion solo asignas `archivo` el cual dudo forma parte de ningun binding